# Cell factory for variable Property

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

In the class model, there are two kinds of Property: `SimpleStringProperty` and `SimpleIntegerProperty`. It is necessary to display them in the form of the `TableView`, where the first column - value name (description) and the second the value itself. Something like this:

[image]

These data wrapping in `Map <String, Property <?>>`, where the K is Value name, and V - Property with a value.

Interested in the following:

1) How should look `CellValueFactory`, that the values are correct "Bind", ie if necessary, they can be changed in a table, and changes are reflected in the class model.

2) Are the property generic correct?

Comment: Can the properties in the map be replaced (using `Map.put` not by modifying values wrapped by the properties)?

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe I misunderstood your question.This map can be replaced by any other type of wrapper. Just seems to me that this type of the most optimal.